# while i am compiling i am getting key error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words):
    return [inverse_vocabulary[word] for word in words]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vocabulary = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/vocabulary.txt").read().split("\n")
    inverse_vocabulary = dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(vocabulary))

    clickbait = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")
    clickbait = sequence.pad_sequences([words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, sentence.split()) for sentence in clickbait], maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

    genuine = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/genuine.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")
    genuine = sequence.pad_sequences([words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, sentence.split()) for sentence in genuine], maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
```

my error is:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-692b7e251048> in <module>()
     25 
     26     clickbait = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")
---> 27     clickbait = sequence.pad_sequences([words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, sentence.split()) for sentence in clickbait], maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
     28 
     29     genuine = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/genuine.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")

<ipython-input-6-692b7e251048> in <listcomp>(.0)
     25 
     26     clickbait = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")
---> 27     clickbait = sequence.pad_sequences([words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, sentence.split()) for sentence in clickbait], maxlen=SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
     28 
     29     genuine = open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/genuine.preprocessed.txt").read().split("\n")

<ipython-input-6-692b7e251048> in words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words)
     16 
     17 def words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words):
---> 18     return [inverse_vocabulary[word] for word in words]
     19 
     20 if __name__ == "__main__":

<ipython-input-6-692b7e251048> in <listcomp>(.0)
     16 
     17 def words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words):
---> 18     return [inverse_vocabulary[word] for word in words]
     19 
     20 if __name__ == "__main__":

KeyError: 'C'
```

Comment: its telling you that the inverse_vocabulary dictionary does not have a key called C. you should modify your function words_to_indices accordingly so it can handle these situations. I would suggest using get so that you return default values when keys don’t exist.

Comment: i didn't understand what you said can you please tell me in deatailed way

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you want to handle missing values but the error is telling you that it comes from this:

```
def words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words):
    return [inverse_vocabulary[word] for word in words]
```

Specifically the issue is `inverse_vocabulary[word]` which will throw a `KeyError` when the key you provide does not exist, in this case the key that is throwing the error is `C`.

Since I don't know how you want to handle missing keys that don't exist I will show you one way to handle this situation so that the error does not get thrown.

```
def words_to_indices(inverse_vocabulary, words):
    return [inverse_vocabulary.get(word, '{} does not exist'.format(word) for word in words]
```

In which case the output of `words_to_indices` should look something like this:

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'C does not exist', etc...]
```

You'll have to modify it to do what you want however.